# Is there a free program that can detect which device on my network is causing lag?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireshark

I'm on a small business network, and rarely we experience really extreme latency.  I have no idea what device might be causing the lag, and wanted to know if there was a piece of software that could detect it.  I know about some softwares like wireshark, which maybe do what I'm asking? If so it's too complicated to understand.  I run the program and I have no idea what I'm looking at, or what parameters to give it.  So something that can monitor traffic, as well as describe it in such a way that even a not so network savvy individual can interpret.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest, lower cost option that I have found for this kind of problems is to use the tool "Airodump-ng" wich is included in some GNU/Linux distributions and can even run on Windows (With additional setup)

You can run a wireless monitoring regarding to your network and see wich device is generating the most traffic (Frames as it is called in the program). There's a column that says "Data", if it isn't getting up at least 200 datas/second, then you probably have an interference problem, could it be from a neighbour WiFi or by a non-WiFi 2.4 GHZ device.

There are dedicated software for this kind of things though, as the Metageek Chanalyzer, wich needs a dedicated USB wireless card and has a cost.

You can also try pinging every device on your network, first with all the devices connected and secondly with only 2 devices at time (The one that pings and the one that responds)

Answer (score 1):

### Set up a full-time traffic graphing application to help identify performance problems.

Setting up a traffic graphing application to monitor your router's interface usage is probably a reasonable place to start in investigating why an office network is under-performing.  Such generally require that you have an always-on system where you can set a polling program up, and leave running 7x24.  While not necessary, if that system can run a web-server, then data can be examined from virtually anywhere.

A traffic graphing application will allow you to determine if demand is exceeding supply (users are requesting more bits/sec than your ISP supplies), if a particular interface is sending/receiving more traffic than usual, or if latency and other performance issues is not related to traffic volume at all.  It can help identify if and when more capacity should be purchased, or if a high network load is an occasional event.  It might even identify a regularly scheduled process that is causing a spike in traffic at the same time each day, or even hour.

While there are many such graphing applications around, one I've used on multiple platforms is [MRTG - Multi-Router Traffic Grapher](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/).  It can monitor traffic on any SNMP capable device:  I've used it to monitor large backbone cisco routers, 48+ port enterprise switches, Linksys routers, even cable and DSL modems.
I recommend any network administrator have this, or a similar application installed, as to keep abreast of network usage patterns.

While there's a slight learning curve involved in installation, once it's configured, its data does not require a high degree of technical expertise to interpret, and it imparts no additional administrative load once configured, as its logfiles do not grow in size.